# What does .trigger('custom') mean if there is no second parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking at a piece of jQuery code:

```
    $(document)
        .trigger('someText')
        .on('click keyup', someMethod);
```

I am unclear as to what `.trigger('someText')` triggers?  What is `someText` referring to?  I can't seem to find it in the code base at all.

The documentation states that for `.trigger('custom') to be useful, you need a second parameter, but there is none.

Comment: That's a custom event name.

Comment: It triggers a `'someText'` event on the document

Comment: There must be an event with the name of 'someText' so trigger('someText') trying to call that event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the posters are correct, that action triggers a custom event; see http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

An example:

```
var btn = $('#button');
var box = $('$box');

btn.on('click', function() {
    box.trigger('hideBox');
});

box.on('hideBox', function() {
    box.hide();
});
```

Comment: Correction, it only triggers a custom jQuery event, which is not an actual DOM event.